# How to refer to a Route53 hosted zone by name in an IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-route53, policy

I have the following IAM policy below:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/Z09248431KGTRJSE3GXXA"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of providing in the Resource section the `zone_id`, is it possible to pass the name of the hosted zone instead?

I am not sure if this is possible. I say this because for whatever reason the hosted zone may get destroyed and created again, which would mean the `zone_id` would change and so would my IAM policy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `route53:ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames` condition key ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/specifying-rrset-conditions.html#route53_rrset_conditionkeys-examples)) for the `ChangeResourceRecordSets` action. Unfortunately, there is no similar condition key for the `ListResourceRecordSets` action.

For example, the following policy will allow the `ChangeResourceRecordSets` operation when all changes have DNS names that end with `".example.com"`

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSetsNormalizedRecordNames": [
                        "*.example.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the IAM wildcard isn't the same as the domain name wildcard. See more examples in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/specifying-rrset-conditions.html#route53_rrset_conditionkeys-examples).